# missing value problem

Tags: self-study, survival, missing-data

I have survival data. However,there are missing values in both categorical and numerical data list. That's, in each column, approximately more than two values are missing.

Now, I want to obtain Kaplan meier function and survival functions and run cox regression.

How can I deal with these missing values to estimate these two functions and to build this regression model?

Comment: How many instances (rows) do you have?

Comment: I have 30 rows @DavideVisentin

Comment: And, all missing values are nearly in different rows. So, row-wise deletion is not useful. I lost all data if I apply deletion method. @DavideVisentin Please help me in this issue.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is to artificially create these missing values by averaging the values in the other rows.

Comment: But that's not easily feasible with categorical data. This paper Batista, G. E., & Monard, M. C. (2003). An analysis of four missing data treatment methods for supervised learning. Applied artificial intelligence, 17(5-6), 519-533 describes several approaches and suggest one based on k-NN. The idea is to replace the missing values with those coming from similar instances. I don't know if it work well in your case, but try taking a look.

Comment: Problems of missing data are complicated. You can look into multiple imputation, but you probably should consult with an expert.

Comment: I am not the consultant you want for this job. I know a bit about missing data, but not enough for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the multiple imputation method to create multiple completed datasets based on which you could do your analysis. From your description, I presume that your outcome of interest is a time-to-event. In this case and because in the multiple imputation procedure it is important that you include the outcome, you should include the estimated log cumulative hazard function for the cases you have survival information. And then perform multiple imputation to fill in the covariates values you miss.

Comment: In fact, I do not understand how to deal with missing data in categorical data. Can you expand your answer for categorical data? Is there any software program and package that you suggest for this? Thanks a lot.